# Приведение типов в стиле функций

Tags: c++, преобразование-типов

Не нашел нигде информацию для приведении типов в стиле вызова функций:

```
int i;
uint ui = uint(i);
```

Мне так больше всего нравится писать в QT. Не знаю, насколько это стандартное поведение и насколько так безопасно писать вместо классических `*_casst<T>(value)`.

Comment: Достаточно грубо, но - считайте это аналогом `reinterpret_cast`...

Comment: а вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Говорить о том, что это "эквивалентно `reinterpret_cast`", разумеется, нельзя. С чего бы это вдруг?

Comment: @AnT Я же сказал - "достаточно грубо", а аналог в том, что позволяет кастить то, что кастить нехорошо. Приведите, скажем, `double*` к `int*` - из `_cast` только `reinterpret` достаточно неприхотлив, ну, и C-кастингу тоже на это плевать. Естественно, это разные вещи, но я говорил в плане опасности применения - и в этом смысле ближе всего `reinterpret`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего нестандартного здесь нет и быть не может. Если приведение типа в функциональной записи имеет *единственный* аргумент, то такое приведение типа эквивалентно во всех отношениях обычному приведению типа в стиле С

```
uint ui = (uint) i;
```

Вы, разумеется, знаете как ведет себя приведению типа в стиле С? Вот так же ведет себя и это приведение типа. В вашем случае это эквивалент `static_cast`.